# Задать допустимый тип для атрибута

Tags: c#, атрибуты

Можно ли в пользовательском атрибуте указать допустимые типы, к которым он может применяться?

К примеру, у меня есть класс с рядом полей, некоторые int, некоторые bool и мой пользовательский атрибут. Я хочу, чтобы при его применении к полям, типизированным int, программа компилировалась, а если его же применить к типу bool - программа выдавала бы ошибку компиляции.

Для наглядности вот пример чего я хочу добиться:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Field | AttributeTargets.Property, AllowMultiple = false, Inherited = false)]
public class MyTypeFilterAttribute : System.Attribute
{
    public MyTypeFilterAttribute(Type t) { }
}

class MyClass
{
    [MyTypeFilter(typeof(int))]
    int Correct;
    [MyTypeFilter(typeof(bool))]
    bool CorrectToo;

    [MyTypeFilter(typeof(int))]
    bool CompilationError;
}
```

Comment: А нельзя отказаться от этих типов, если они должны совпадать с типом поля/свойства?
То что вы просите можно сделать только в рантайме, когда конструкторы атрибутов будут вызваны.
Единственный вариант который я вижу это Post-build event в msbuild, который будет прогонять нужные проверки.

Comment: Ответа не знаю, но можно бросать исключение, если тип недопустимый. А вообще для таких штук есть Generic.

Comment: Похоже что тс хочет сделать что-то вроде енумератора?

Comment: Написать Roslyn-анализатор.

Comment: Все куда проще. У мея будут поля в классе которые будут оптимизироваться. Т.е. аттрибут будет показывать минимальное и максимальное допустимые значения поля, и эти значения будут перебираться и присваваться соответствующим полям в рантайме. По этому будет ошибка если случайно декорируют стринговым к примеру аттрибутом интовое поле. В общем для удобства это нужно в основном.